# Can you mount a Dell U2711 monitor with an Ergotron LX?

Tags: display

Has anyone reading this mounted the Dell U2711 with the Ergotron LX arm?

I'm asking because the specs for the LX say up to 24" and a max of 20lbs. I'm assuming the inches aren't as important as the weight, so if a bigger monitor weighs less than 20lbs it would be fine? If that is true, the trouble is I can't figure out how much the U2711 weighs.

[Here Dell says](http://accessories.us.dell.com/sna/productdetail.aspx?c=us&l=en&cs=19&sku=224-8284&baynote_bnrank=1&baynote_irrank=0&~ck=baynoteSearch) it weighs 17.02lbs with it's stand, in which case the LX should easily support it?

[But here CNET says](http://reviews.cnet.com/lcd-monitors/dell-ultrasharp-u2711/4507-3174_7-33913833.html) it weighs 23.1lbs?

On one form someone suggest that on the dell site it may be a typo and the 17.01lbs is without the stand, but can anyone verify that?

Thanks!!

Comment: Did you ever try this configuration out?  I'm considering the same.

Answer (score 3):

Yes - it works ok, not great. I'm using a U2711 mounted an Ergotron LX to type this answer. I've been using it for a few days in this setup.

I think it's a *little* too heavy because it's quite bouncy - it wobbles slightly if I push on the desk or nudge the monitor. It doesn't actually sag and get lower though, so I don't need to readjust its height when this happens, just wait for it to stop bouncing.

It might be possible to reduce the wobbling by increasing the tension, but I'm past the point of tedium turning the tension screw. It's so far in that I can't get to it with the short end of a standard allen wrench, and the monitor still wobbles.

Overall it is usable in this setup. I don't have any plans to take it off the Ergotron.

Answer (score 2):

I've mounted a U3011 on one; you just have to tension the hell out of it so it won't sag.  No promises, since the arm was being used with some other custom mounting, but it should be okay.  I would NOT recommend more than one LX extender.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. How much does the U3011 weigh? What are the LX extenders - I assume to give it more reach?

Comment: I don't know the weights offhand, but it's got to be near or more than the U2711 since it's basically the same design, just bigger. And yes on the extender - the LX arm is the actual lift arm, then another extender piece (the articulating part), then whatever your mount of choice is.  You can buy additional extender pieces (necessary if you want to do, say, 3 24" monitors left-to-right on one mount, because otherwise the arms aren't long enough).